# How to run cron in serverless for every minute?

Tags: node.js, cron, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

I need to run cron for every minute for my server less

```
rate: cron(* * * * * *)
```

But it throws me error

```
  An error occurred: SendNotificationsEventsRuleSchedule1 - Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid. (Service: AmazonCloudWatchEvents; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID:XXXXXXXXXX.
```

Comment: Please add more details about your setup and/or hoe to reproduce.

Comment: @damitj07 Nothing more. I know serverless cron is slight different syntax from the other ones. I need to know the exact format for one minute cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the manpage it should be just like the following:

```
rate: rate(1 minute)
```

Or in more context from the serverless.yml:

```
functions:    
  aggregate:    
    handler: statistics.handler    
    events:    
      - schedule:    
          rate: rate(1 minute)
```

More info https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/schedule/

Answer (score 0):

functions:

myjob:
handler: handler.myjob
events:
- schedule: rate(1 minute)

Source: https://www.serverless.com/blog/cron-jobs-on-aws